# I want to do practical for puppet with docker

Tags: docker, puppet

I want to do practical of puppet with docker.
I mean puppet server(chef server) will be docker container and puppet client (Chef servers) will be docker container. 
So can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Puppet? Chef? You understand they are two different technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 194 containers about puppet at https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=puppet&searchfield=  you should find what you want and at least ideas on how to achieve it.